# Incorrect cumulative flow diagram in Visual Studio Online (TFS)

Tags: visual-studio-2012, tfs, azure-devops

I have a backlog of a project with no committed PBIs. However the cumulative flow diagram is showing as it there were items in that state. It also happens with PBIs in New state; I have "grey" area corresponding to "New" items in the CFD but none appears in the main backlog with that state.

I run a query looking for PBIs in "New" or "Committed" state but the report returns 0 items.

I am missing something? Below the current status of my CFD:

[My CFD status now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7d3MO.png)

Thank you very much!!

Comment: There is a guy in Microsoft's MSDN asking the same question > http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/27c4c89e-2b83-457c-8113-5399b4045c58/team-foundation-server-2012-cumulative-flow-diagram-query?forum=tfsworkitemtracking

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue has been solved [in July's 1st update of Visual Studio Online](http://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/news/2014-07-01-vso).